# How to change default action of golang tags?

Tags: json, go, tags, bson

I am not familiar with usage of `golang tags`, I want to change the default action of convertion:

```
type CvJdRelationInfo struct {
    JdId            string
    CvId            string
    Status          int16
    AcceptTimestamp int64
}
```

`json` tag will auto convert:

```
JdId -> JdId
CvId -> CvId
Status -> Status
AcceptTimestamp -> AcceptTimestamp
```

`bson` tag will auto convert:

```
JdId -> jdid
CvId -> cvid
Status -> status
AcceptTimestamp -> accepttimestamp
```

Can I change the default action, such as `json` `bson` tags will do this:

```
JdId -> jdId
CvId -> cvId
Status -> status
AcceptTimestamp -> acceptTimeStamp
```

So I can omission all tags each time(why should I write tags each time if default action is just what I want?)

```
type CvJdRelationInfo struct {
    JdId            string `json:"jdId" bson:"jdId"`
    CvId            string `json:"cvId" bson:"cvId"`
    Status          int16  `json:"status" bson:"status"`
    AcceptTimestamp int64  `json:"acceptTimestamp" bson:"acceptTimestamp"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
   type CvJdRelationInfo struct {
     JdId            string    `bson:"jdId" json:"jdId"`
     CvId            string    `bson:"cvId" json:"cvId"`
     Status          int16     `bson:"status" json"status"`
     AcceptTimestamp int64     `bson:"acceptTimeStamp" json:"acceptTimeStamp"`
   }
```

Comment: Anyway, I know this, but I need to do this each time I define a struct, what I want to do is without append the tags, the default action will work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default behavior of the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package. It's built into it and there is no exported variable or function which would change it. Nothing to discuss on it.

> The object's default key string is the struct field name but can be specified in the struct field's tag value.

One thing to note here is that even though marshaling a value to JSON will use the exported, uppercased name, but when you unmarshal, the `json` package is "intelligent" enough to match lowercased names to uppercased field names too.

See this example:

```
s := struct{ X, Y int }{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"X":1,"y":2}`), &s); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v", s)
```

It will print ([Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/fvylv9RP_L)):

```
{X:1 Y:2}
```

The `json` package properly matches the `"X"` and `"y"` keys to the `s.X` and `s.Y` fields even though `"y"` is written lowercased.